# How to use ChartJS object in a click event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, echarts

I have 3 ChartJS objects that I am drawing on my dashboard page. I'm also using echarts.js in the same page for pie chart. I am having a click event on pie chart where different data is drawn on ChartJS charts for click event of each pie. So I'm using ChartJS objects in click event of pie chart. But the ChartJS objects become undefined inside the handler even though I defined it globally. 
And I got the error for destroy() as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined".

My question is how can I access ChartJS objects in echarts click event handler?

Please refer to my sample of code below:

```
pie.on('click', function (params) { //pie is the object of echart 
  console.log(myChart);//printing myChart results "undefined" in console
  var thatState = params.name;
  myChart.destroy();
  waitChart.destroy();
  myBarChart.destroy();
  console.log("destroyed!");

  //myChart,waitChart,myBarChart are the objects of 
  // chartJS. I'm destroying those to redraw the charts with new data on 
  // click event of pies.
..............
........
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure it's *really* global:

```
console.log(window.myChart);
```

---

1: Try to pass it as a param somehow (if possible):

```
pie.on('click', function(params, myChart) {
    console.log(myChart);
});
```

2: Try ES6 arrow notation, to be able to access the scope outside of the function block:

```
pie.on('click', (params) => {
    console.log(window.myChart);
});
```

3: Map it to `this`, and access it in the function block:

```
this.myChart = myChart || window.myChart;
pie.on('click', (params) => {
    console.log(this.myChart);
});
```